# is there a fused instruction that can perform a * 10^n in a single instruction?

Tags: java, floating-point, cpu

Calling `a * pow(10.0, n)`, in any C derived language, results in two rounding errors, but I require only one rounding error as can be provided by a single fused instruction.

For example `a=39762108874335653 n=-297` should give `3.9762108874335653E-281` (as can be validated by parsing the string `"3.9762108874335653E-281"` or using arbitrary precision arithmetic, and outputting a floating point number) but the quoted code returns `3.976210887433566E-281`.

That leads back to the question: is there a fused instruction (or C function) that can perform this calculation to the highest possible precision for the machine?

I am only concerned with the case where `a` and `n` are integers, and the result is a double precision floating point number. Note that `a` may not be exactly representable as a floating point number.

Converting to a string and parsing is not an acceptable solution (it's far too slow), nor is using an arbitrary precision library (such as Java's `BigDecimal`, also because it's too slow).

Note that there is a similar C stdlib function, `ldexp` (related to `scalbn`) which uses base2 and therefore calculates `a * 2^n` as a single fused instruction.

I am aware of the instructions listed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_mathematical_functions

Not a dupe of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004) this is not about trying to understand how rounding works. It is just asking: does this function exist anywhere, ideally in a CPU fused instruction for maximum performance? Obviously the workaround in the absense of such a thing is to use arbitrary precision, but that is quite heavyweight.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216262/discussion-on-question-by-fommil-is-there-a-fused-instruction-that-can-perform-a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "no" there is not a single instruction that can perform this operation, as answered by [@eric-postpischil in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49691296#49691296) and the evidence for this can be backed up by the fact that standard libraries would use it if it were available, e.g. [glibc strtod](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/stdlib/strtod_l.c)

However, although there is no single CPU instruction, it is possible to extract the strtod implementation to operate on the integer input as requested in this question, as was done by [Alex Huszagh](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/a6j5j1/making_rust_float_parsing_fast_and_correct) in Rust. The algorithms discussed here effectively use `a * pow(10.0, n)` when the significand is estimated to be small enough (preferring division for negative n) and falling back to converge algorithms to eliminate the rounding errors.